C# How to get null state analysis to recognise returned object cannot be null
I'm trying to start using null state analysis in our application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references
I've run in to the following issue: (with a new C# console app)
public interface ITester
{
    string GetString();
}

public class Test(ITester t)
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var x = t.GetString();
    }
}

When I hover over "var x" it is shown as being of type string? whereas I want the interace to enforce nullability, so that the return object of GetString really is string, not string?.
This is the same behaviour for other returned types too, the example here is just to keep it simple.
I expected the compiler to know the object returned via the interface cannot be null (because I have <Nullable>enable</Nullable> set), but it doesn't seem to.
What would I need to change here for it to realise that the "var x" variable is string instead of string?:

You need to hover over one of the usages of x, and see the text which says "x is not null here"

This is a constant source of confusion, even though it was done for very good reasons, and makes a lot of sense once you understand how the flow state work with NRTs. Arguably the most confusing thing is the ? in the intellisense pop-up. I've linked your question to a bunch of others which have answers which hopefully make the situation clearer

Yes I see that if I get x.Length, however x is still type string? not string. I don't know why it's not being recognised as type string (if it knows it's not null)

Please read the other questions (and answers!) I linked. There is a very good reason to do with re-assigning variables later in the method, and it turns out that it doesn't matter because you actually care about the flow state of the variable, not its nullability annotations. These are explained at length in the answers I've linked.
